# force gridview rows to row hight

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a table that comes from Access. added the datasource and get this in the grid view. There is a column called comments. This column can have a lot of text in it. When I run it in internet explorer, the rows are inflated to show all the text. Even if I set the row hight in the code, it still pops up like that. I did a lot of google searches, but all points to the row hight, but I can't make it work.

Is there something I missed out? or it simply does force the row hight  to fit all text?

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying this CSS to hide the extra stuff.

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 50px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: To be honest, and since I'm new to asp.net and visual studio, I have no clue where to add the ccs line.
I went into the edit column and selected wrap to false in the Item style.

Comment: You can add it in the header of your page under <style> tag.